# how to convert mp4 to flv in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new  in nodejs. I need to convert any video to .flv format. Is it possible  to video conversion in nodejs. i tried the below

```
var converter = require('format-converter');

converter.setFfmpegPath("ffmpeg");


converter.convert("/home/ults/Downloads/Best Catches in Cricket History! Best Acrobatic Catches! (Please comment the best catch).mp4", "/home/ults/Best Catches in Cricket History! Best Acrobatic Catches! (Please comment the best catch).mp3", function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("done");
});

// get the percentage
converter.on("progress", function(percentage) {
    console.log(percentage);
});
```

please help..

Comment: What's the output of your current code? What's the problem with it? It's one thing to provide an example, but not everyone is able to test it and explaining your problem could help us help you!

Comment: i got this error : Cannot find module 'format-converter'

Comment: This would imply that you need to install that module - but looking at npm, that's not a module that exists anyway.

Comment: i already installed the module

Comment: Can you link me to where you got the module from? Preferably npmjs website if plausible.

Comment: Is their any alternative ways for this

Comment: Possibly if you linked me to the library you're using (or attempting to) so I understand what features you were looking for!

Comment: this is the link i reffered: https://libraries.io/npm/video-converter